# VBA - Split from right to left (REVERSED)

Tags: vba, split

I want to extract the last folder from a folder path:

```
path = C:\Users\z204685\tecware\RESULTS\D1369_3 (R=0) Surface Failure
```

I want to extract the last part, after the "\", in a new string:

```
newString = "D1369_3 (R=0) Surface Failure"
```

Maybe reversing the path string, then using the Split function with "\" and then reversing it again...Any better ideas?

Comment: Locate the position of the last "\", then extract the string from there. `Mid` should help you for that

Comment: `Split(path,"\")` and take the last element from the resulting array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my stab at it:

```
Sub test()
    Dim testString As String
    Dim test As Long
    Dim output As String

    testString = "C:\Users\z204685\tecware\RESULTS\D1369_3 (R=0) Surface Failure"

    test = InStrRev(testString, "\")

    output = Right(testString, Len(testString) - test)

End Sub
```

Hope it gets you close!

Comment: It does indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look up the `InStrRev` function.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, according to @TimWilliams comment, You can achieve this using `Split` and `UBound`

```
Sub test()

Dim fpath As String
Dim newString As String
Dim temp_arr As Variant

fpath = "C:\Users\z204685\tecware\RESULTS\D1369_3 (R=0) Surface Failure"
temp_arr = Split(fpath, "\")
newString = temp_arr(UBound(temp_arr))

End Sub
```